# Sorting In Python

Tags: python

```
#Wednesday 11th February 2015 By Daniel B Scanlon
#Sorting Homework
import operator
pay = {}
pay["Developers"]=[35,22,18,36]
pay["Designers"]=[25,65,24,45]
pay["Testers"]=[34,52,12,32]
userInput=int(input("How would you like the menu to be sorted?\n1 for     Dictionary keys sorted in alphabetical order\n2 for Sort each list of employee’s pay rates from highest to lowest\n3 for Lowest pay level in each list sorted from highest to lowest\n4 for Average pay per department sorted from highest to lowest"))
if userInput == 1:
    for key,value in pay.items():
        sortedDictionary = sorted(pay)
     print (sortedDictionary)
if userInput == 2:
    for key,value in pay.items():
        value.sort()
        value.reverse()
        print(key,value)
if userInput == 3:
    for key,value in pay.items():
        value.sort()
        pay [key]=value.pop()
        lowestPay =   sorted(pay.items(),key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
    print (lowestPay)
```

In the third `if` statement I am trying to get the highest value from each list and and then print them with the keys assigned to them from highest to lowest and when I run I am getting a error saying

```
  ... line 22, in <module>
    lowestPay = sorted(pay.items(),key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
TypeError: unorderable types: int() < list()
```

Comment: Why are you replacing each value in `pay` with a single integer from `value` before sorting?

Comment: i am not a 100% sure what you mean but if its what i think your talking about its because i have been asked to find the highest pay rate in each list so i have ordered them then took the last one and added it to a different dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to sort lists:

```
sorted(pay.items(),key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
```

Here `operator.itemgetter(1)` gets each *value* from the `pay` dictionary.

However, you replaced **one** value with an integer:

```
value.sort()
pay [key]=value.pop()
```

That's the highest value from the original list, and you replaced the whole list with that lowest value.

So you had this:

```
>>> pay
{'Designers': [25, 65, 24, 45], 'Developers': [35, 22, 18, 36], 'Testers': [34, 52, 12, 32]}
```

then in your loop took *one* of those keys and replaced the value:

```
>>> key = 'Designers'
>>> value = pay[key]
>>> value
[25, 65, 24, 45]
>>> value.sort()
>>> pay[key] = value.pop()
>>> pay
{'Designers': 65, 'Developers': [35, 22, 18, 36], 'Testers': [34, 52, 12, 32]}
```

Note how `pay['Designers']` is now no longer a list. It is a single integer. You now can no longer sort your dictionary items as you cannot compare a single integer to the other lists:

```
>>> sorted(pay.items(),key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: int() < list()
```

If you wanted to find the highest pay rate, I'd use the [`max()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) here, and use it *twice*, once in the key function to select the highest value from the list:

```
highest_rate = max(pay.items(), key=lambda i: max(i[1]))
```

This returns the `key, value` pair for the job title with the highest rate:

```
>>> pay = {'Designers': [25, 65, 24, 45], 'Developers': [35, 22, 18, 36], 'Testers': [34, 52, 12, 32]}
>>> max(pay.items(), key=lambda i: max(i[1]))
('Designers', [25, 65, 24, 45])
```